# VerifyError in Android 11 debug mode: Rejecting class com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, mime-message

On Android, we use a MimeMessageParser from org.apache.commons.mail.util to parse a mime object into a javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage object.
To enable that, we install a MailcapCommandMap, e.g.
`mailcap.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");`

When i run the app in debug mode on an Android 11 (API 30) x86 emulator or an Android 11 device (Pixel 4a), the MailcapCommandMap class throws a VerifyError:

`Rejecting class com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed that attempts to sub-type erroneous class com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base (declaration of 'com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed'`

with the cause given as

`java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base: java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[] com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base.getTransferDataFlavors() failed to verify: java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[] com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base.getTransferDataFlavors(): [0x4]  can't resolve returned type 'Unresolved Reference: java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[]' or 'Reference: javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor[]'`

Similar errors seem to related to Proguard resp R8, but obfuscation is disabled, and the exact same code runs in a release build.
As this only happens on Android 11 emulators, and javamail seems to use reflection, i wonder if that behavior can be avoided somehow.

Edit: The responsible code seems to be this:

```
// First try the "application's" class loader.
cld = SecuritySupport.getContextClassLoader();
if (cld == null)
cld = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
Class cl = null;
try {
cl = cld.loadClass(name);
} catch (Exception ex) {
// if anything goes wrong, do it the old way
cl = Class.forName(name);
}
if (cl != null)     // XXX - always true?
return (DataContentHandler)cl.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the mail library. see https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/issues/489

It is fixed with version 1.6.6 or 2.0.0